# How to make pagination and filters with ASP.NET Core Web API 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm having problems to makes pagination and filters with ASP.NET Web API at version 2.2 do .NET Core.

I tryed find a solution like the PagedList, but seems that not exists anything for ASP.NET Core. So I started to implement some solution to my problem and her is like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<TripListViewModel>> GetTrips([FromQuery]TripsPaginationFilterViewModel model)
{
    var trips = await _viagemRepository.GetList(model.Page, model.Limit);

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TripListViewModel>>(trips);
}

public class TripsPaginationFilterViewModel : PaginationFilterViewModel
{
   public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateFinish { get; set; }
   public Guid TrechoId { get; set; }
}

public class PaginationFilterViewModel
{
   public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
   public int Limit { get; set; } = 20;
   public bool IncludeInactivs { get; set; } = false;
}

public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetList(int page, int limit, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    if (predicate!= null)
    {
        return await DbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
    }

    return await DbSet.AsNoTracking().Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit).ToListAsync();
}
```

I would like to know how to tell the predicate as a parameter to the method of my repository filtering.

Comment: There's a fork of PagedList, called X.PagedList, that works with .NET Core and lives [here](https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList).

Comment: @Kirk Larkin But the X.PagedList and PagedList solves only to MVC, with Views in HTML, or exists some implementation to Web API?

Comment: What do you mean by `only to MVC`? Call `ToPagedList` off of your IEnumerable/IQueryable passing in the page size and you will get your expected result. Youc could call `ToPagedList` in your repository.

Comment: you can use Gridify for that. it's a clean and easy way to do Filtering, Ordering, and pagination in your APIs.
https://github.com/Alirezanet/Gridify

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the following code into your project somewhere and you'll have access to a full IQueryable supported PagedListCollection. Its taken from one of my projects. It sits as extension methods to IQueryable and IEnumerable calls and allows you to do .ToPagedList() on your queries to return a paged collection

```
namespace Simple.Data.Pagination.Extensions
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Interfaces;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides some extension methods for <see cref="IEnumerable{T}" /> to provide paging capability.
    /// </summary>
    public static class EnumerablePagedListExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified source to <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> by the specified <paramref name="pageIndex" /> and
        /// <paramref name="pageSize" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the source.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source to paging.</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">The index of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The size of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="indexFrom">The start index value.</param>
        /// <param name="totalCount">The Total Count</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of the inherited from <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> interface.</returns>
        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int indexFrom = 0, int totalCount = 0) => new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified source to <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> by the specified <paramref name="pageIndex" /> and
        /// <paramref name="pageSize" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the source.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source to paging.</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">The index of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The size of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="indexFrom">The start index value.</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of the inherited from <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> interface.</returns>
        public static IPagedList<T> ToPagedList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int indexFrom = 0) => new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize, indexFrom);

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified source to <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> by the specified <paramref name="converter" />,
        /// <paramref name="pageIndex" /> and <paramref name="pageSize" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source to convert.</param>
        /// <param name="converter">The converter to change the <typeparamref name="TSource" /> to <typeparamref name="TResult" />.</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">The page index.</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The page size.</param>
        /// <param name="indexFrom">The start index value.</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of the inherited from <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> interface.</returns>
        public static IPagedList<TResult> ToPagedList<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> converter, int pageIndex, int pageSize,
            int indexFrom = 0) => new PagedList<TSource, TResult>(source, converter, pageIndex, pageSize, indexFrom);
    }
}


namespace Simple.Data.Pagination.Extensions
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Interfaces;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

    /// <summary>
    /// Extensions for the <see cref="IPagedList{T}"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static class QueryablePageListExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the specified source to <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> by the specified <paramref name="pageIndex" /> and <paramref name="pageSize" />
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the source</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source to paging</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">The index of the page</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The size of the page</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A <see cref="CancellationToken" /> to observe while waiting for the task to complete</param>
        /// <param name="indexFrom">The start index value</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of the inherited from <see cref="IPagedList{T}"/> interface</returns>
        public static async Task<IPagedList<T>> ToPagedListAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int indexFrom = 0, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (indexFrom > pageIndex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"indexFrom: {indexFrom} > pageNumber: {pageIndex}, must indexFrom <= pageNumber");
            }

            var count = await source.CountAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - indexFrom) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var pagedList = new PagedList<T>
            {
                PageNumber = pageIndex,
                PageSize = pageSize,
                IndexFrom = indexFrom,
                TotalCount = count,
                Items = items,
                TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize)
            };

            return pagedList;
        }
    }
}


namespace Simple.Data.Pagination.Interfaces
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the interface(s) for paged list of any type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type for paging.</typeparam>
    public interface IPagedList<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Index Start Value
        /// </summary>
        int IndexFrom { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Page Number
        /// </summary>
        int PageNumber { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Page Size
        /// </summary>
        int PageSize { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Total Count of the list of <typeparamref name="T" />
        /// </summary>
        int TotalCount { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Total Pages
        /// </summary>
        int TotalPages { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Current Page Items
        /// </summary>
        IList<T> Items { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the paged list has a previous page
        /// </summary>
        bool HasPreviousPage { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the paged list has a next page
        /// </summary>
        bool HasNextPage { get; }
    }
}

namespace Simple.Data.Pagination
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Interfaces;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the default implementation of the <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> interface
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the data to page</typeparam>
    public class PagedList<T> : IPagedList<T>
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int IndexFrom { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IList<T> Items { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool HasPreviousPage => this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom > 0;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool HasNextPage => this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom + 1 < this.TotalPages;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PagedList{T}" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The Source Collection</param>
        /// <param name="pageNumber">The Page Number</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The Page Size</param>
        /// <param name="totalCount">The Total Item Count</param>
        public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalCount)
        {
            this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.IndexFrom = pageNumber * pageSize;

            var itemList = source.ToList();
            this.TotalCount = totalCount;
            this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalCount / (double)this.PageSize);

            this.Items = itemList.Skip(this.IndexFrom).Take(this.PageSize).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PagedList{T}" /> class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The Source Collection</param>
        /// <param name="pageNumber">The Page Number</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The Page Size</param>
        public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
            this.PageSize = pageSize;
            this.IndexFrom = pageNumber * pageSize;
            this.TotalCount = source.Count();
            this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalCount / (double)this.PageSize);
            this.Items = source.Skip(this.IndexFrom).Take(this.PageSize).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PagedList{T}" /> class
        /// </summary>
        public PagedList()
        {
            this.Items = new T[0];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides the implementation of the <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> and Converter
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the source.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result.</typeparam>
    public class PagedList<TSource, TResult> : IPagedList<TResult>
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int PageNumber { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int PageSize { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int TotalCount { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int TotalPages { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public int IndexFrom { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public IList<TResult> Items { get; }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool HasPreviousPage => this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom > 0;

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool HasNextPage => this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom + 1 < this.TotalPages;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PagedList{TSource, TResult}" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="converter">The converter.</param>
        /// <param name="pageIndex">The index of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">The size of the page.</param>
        /// <param name="indexFrom">The index from.</param>
        public PagedList(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> converter, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int indexFrom)
        {
            if (source is IQueryable<TSource> queryable)
            {
                this.PageNumber = pageIndex;
                this.PageSize = pageSize;
                this.IndexFrom = indexFrom;
                this.TotalCount = queryable.Count();
                this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalCount / (double)this.PageSize);

                var items = queryable.Skip((this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom) * this.PageSize).Take(this.PageSize).ToArray();
                this.Items = new List<TResult>(converter(items));
            }
            else
            {
                this.PageNumber = pageIndex;
                this.PageSize = pageSize;
                this.IndexFrom = indexFrom;

                var itemList = source.ToList();
                this.TotalCount = itemList.Count;
                this.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalCount / (double)this.PageSize);

                var items = itemList.Skip((this.PageNumber - this.IndexFrom) * this.PageSize).Take(this.PageSize).ToArray();
                this.Items = new List<TResult>(converter(items));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PagedList{TSource, TResult}" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The source.</param>
        /// <param name="converter">The converter.</param>
        public PagedList(IPagedList<TSource> source, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> converter)
        {
            this.PageNumber = source.PageNumber;
            this.PageSize = source.PageSize;
            this.IndexFrom = source.IndexFrom;
            this.TotalCount = source.TotalCount;
            this.TotalPages = source.TotalPages;
            this.Items = new List<TResult>(converter(source.Items));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides some help methods for <see cref="IPagedList{T}" /> interface.
    /// </summary>
    public static class PagedList
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an empty of <see cref="IPagedList{T}" />.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type for paging</typeparam>
        /// <returns>An empty instance of <see cref="IPagedList{T}" />.</returns>
        public static IPagedList<T> Empty<T>() => new PagedList<T>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="IPagedList{TResult}" /> from source of <see cref="IPagedList{TSource}" />
        /// instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult">The Type of the Result</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">The Type of the Source</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The Source</param>
        /// <param name="converter">The Converter</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="IPagedList{TResult}" />.</returns>
        public static IPagedList<TResult> From<TResult, TSource>(IPagedList<TSource> source, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TResult>> converter) => new PagedList<TSource, TResult>(source, converter);
    }
}
```